# Android: Runtime Exception in doInBackground

Tags: android

I'm not able to find whats wrong with this code. Someone please help me out. I used same code in other project as well and in that project it worked fine. I'm just trying to open a URL to load it in a `WebView` and I already gave internet permission in the `manifest` file. 
Here's the code:

```
package com.example.itmuantiragging;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView; 
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class Fragment_Website extends Fragment {

WebView wv;
ProgressDialog pg;
Background bg;

public Fragment_Website() {}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_website, container,false);

    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Loading... Please Wait..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    wv = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    bg = new Background();
    bg.execute();

    return rootView;
}

 public void progress(){
        pg = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pg.setTitle("");
        pg.setMessage("Please Wait.........");
        pg.setCancelable(false);
        pg.setIndeterminate(true);
        pg.show();
    }

    class Background extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                try{
                    wv.loadUrl("http://www.siddharth.uphero.com/MTNL_address_locator.html");
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
                    wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
                    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                    wv.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient()); 


            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {




        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            progress();
        }
    }
     public class MyWebClient extends WebViewClient
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                         pg.dismiss();

            }
        }


}
```

Comment: Care to post what the exception is, with the stacktrace pointing to your code? Or is this a riddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you are doing background operation as `WebView` has it's own method to handle it. You use `WebView` right so you can directly load URL in android `WebView` using the following method.

```
webview.loadUrl(url)
```

So now question is how to show progress bar. Ok there is build in method `onPageStarted()` and `onPageFinished()` where you can start progress and stop progress. Move the following code inside `onCreateView()` method.

```
   wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
                    wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
                    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                    wv.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient());
```

Hope it make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can only update views on the UI thread.

Comment: I used the same code before as well and it worked..

Comment: someone please tell me where is the exact problem?

Comment: but where he is updating UI in non UI thread?

Comment: @Gopal Rao: at the line: wv.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient());